# Why p-linear alternating form evaluated on linearly dependent set of vectors is zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

From pg. 2 of *Differential Geometry, Gauge Theories and Gravity* by Göckeler & Schücker:
[image]

How can it be shown that it is true that a p-linear altenating form is zero when evaluated on a linearly dependent set of vectors?

I managed to show that this is true for $p=2$ but don't know how to generalize to arbitrary $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_p\}$ is linearly dependant, and without loss of generality, assume that $v_p = \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \lambda_j v_j$.
Let $\omega$ be any $p$-alternate form.
Then by multilinearity, it holds that
\begin{align}
\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_p) &= \omega(v_1,\ldots,v_{p-1},\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\lambda_jv_j) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\lambda_j\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_{p-1},v_j).
\end{align}

To conclude, it suffices to show that each $\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_{p-1},v_j)$ is zero.
Applying the transposition $(j,n)$ to the entries, we see that
$\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_{p-1},v_j)=-\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_{p-1},v_j)$, and finally that $2\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_{p-1},v_j)=0$.
The result follows.
Note that this proof shows that this is also the case over a field of characteristic different from $2$.